# Scala collection map var to another value

Tags: scala

I have a collection `col` with elements of type `Foo`.

`Foo` has a `var bar`, which I need to change for every element in the collection.

Currently my code looks like this

```scala
col.map(baz => {
  baz.bar = <something>
  baz
})
```

Is there a nicer way to do this? I feel like this could be done with a one liner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`foreach` is designed for side-effects like that

```
col.foreach(_.bar = <something>)
```

after this `col` will have all elements mutated. If you wish to avoid `Unit` return type try chaining

```
import util.chaining._
col.map(_.tap(_.bar = <something>))
```

or other way around

```
col.tap(_.foreach(_.bar = <something>))
```

Idimoatic approach would be to avoid `var` and have immutable case class `Foo` then `copy`

```
col.map(_.copy(bar = <something>))
```

Comment: Thanks, `foreach` is of type `Unit` though, is there a way that returns the new collection?

Comment: Thanks! Using `tap` worked perfectly for me!

Comment: @Tschösi there is no much point in returning a new collection since the original one also has the data modified.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I agree, I want to return the _new_ collection (which I think `tap` does)